# Doctrine DQL join tables

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, laminas-api-tools

for my API development I use apigility and **doctrine**. I'm currently programming an endpoint that users can like a post. Every post has an author. I have 2 tables with the following columns and example data inside:

**Action**

```
id  post_id   user_id  createdAt
1   10        1        0000-00-00 00:00:00
2   12        2        0000-00-00 00:00:00
3   13        3        0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

*(post_id = foreign key to post table)*
*(user_id = source user which likes a post)*

**Post**

```
id  user_id   createdAt
10  62        0000-00-00 00:00:00
12  4         0000-00-00 00:00:00
13  4         0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

*(user_id = foreign key to user table)*

**What I need**

I need the total_likes which an author (user_id) has. This can be queried over the Action table by joining the post table. I have already tried to create a DQL query for this:

```
// Get total likes an autor has received
$queryBuilder->select('count(p)')
    ->from('Db\Entity\Action', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('p.post', 'p')
    ->where('p.user = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $targetUser);
$totalLikes = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Which this query, I get the wrong number of total_likes:

```
{
  "total_likes": "2"
}
```

How do I have to correct this query that I get the correct count of likes of a user? With the example table data, the total_likes of user_id=62 should give me this back:

```
{
  "total_likes": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Get total likes an autor has received
$queryBuilder
    ->select('count(p)')
    ->from('Db\Entity\Action', 'a')
    ->leftJoin(
        'Db\Entity\Post',
        'p',
        \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
        'a.post = p.id'
     )
     ->where('p.user = :user')
     ->setParameter('user', $users);

    $totalLikes = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome! Worked perfectly :-)